# div into link or div as href in haml

Tags: html

Given this

```
<div class='postpreview'>
  <a href="/some/image/xyz"><img alt="xyz" src="/some/image/xyz" /></a>
  Some content, etc.
  <a href='/forums/post/123'>Show</a>
</div>
```

How can I make the entire div 'postpreview' function as link to '/forums/post/123'? In haml?

Basically this is within a rails partial, and the links are listed as link_to, etc (another issue altogether). I can get the above to work fine in haml, I just cannot turn the entire div into a link without either an error or the output showing up on the page but not linking. I'd like to get rid of the 'Show' link and make the entire postpreview link to the post.

Comment: Nothing to do with rails.. rails is server side, you're trying to alter the output to provide a link so this is a pure html/javascript question.

Comment: Yes, I understand, but was providing the context in which this is being done.

Answer (score 2):

You'd need to use JavaScript to add a click hanlder to the div element. For example, if you give the particular div an id it is as simple as:

```
document.getElementById('myDivID').onclick = function() {
    window.location = '/forums/post/123'; 
}
```

Or if you're using jQuery:

```
$('#myDivId').click(function() { window.location = ... });
```

Note that you've got two links within the div - is it intentional to make the first link impossible to follow?

Comment: One is to an image, which remains unchanged, the other gets attached to the entire div.

Comment: I'd like to avoid javascript for this solution...I'm certain there is pure css/html solution.

Comment: Re-read my comment. The image's link is inside the div. If you attach a click handler to the div that the redirects the user to one URI, it will override the link to the image. Is that intentional?

Comment: Wrapping <div>s in <a href="#whatever"> causes issues in IE6 -- that's where the JS solution would come in handy.

Comment: You could wrap the div in an anchor, but that would be invalid html, so no, there is no proper css/html solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think Hamish is sure right with his question.. What about the first link? Do you need it? Else you could just kill the first  and go with some pure HTML/CSS solution which extends every a in a div with the class postpreview:

HTML

```
<div class="postpreview">
 <a href="/forums/post/123" rel="bookmark" title="Foo">
  <img src="/some/image/xyz.jpg" alt="foo" title="bar" />  
 </a>                        
</div>
```

CSS

```
.postpreview a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

respectively set the height and width of the a element according to your image size or better the surrounding div.

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution -- a link to the image itself would be nice, or rather is the next step - generating this postpreview that links to post with the thumbnail inside linking to the image

The line prefaced by / does not work so well, but the open image_tag line does link to page the post is on, no js required.

```
.postpreview
 %a{:href =>(url_for [@blog, post])}
  .postcontaincontain
   = image_tag(post.image_url(:thumb)) if post.image_url
   /= link_to image_tag(post.image_url(:thumb)), post.image_url if post.image_url
   = shout.content
```

Comment: tobiasmay, your solution was helpful.

Comment: glas you worked it out. since i have no clue of haml i couldn't help you there :) but if something worked for you, please mark it as solved, so other users find solutions quicker.